# Element to the bottom of the screen with a scroll under it

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

It is my first time participating to StackOverflow so if you have tips don't keep them for you ;)

I am actually using Ionic React to create a mobile app, and I am blocking on a problem that seems more a **React-CSS problem**.

On this page (image) the content under the header is in a [IonContent](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/content) which seems to allow me to have an overflow by the bottom.

[**Image of the page**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bzV0l.png)

**My problem**
My goal is to have the brown part at bottom to really be touching the bottom on the initial loading, so having the image taking the rest of the screen height.
I also want to have some content under this button so that the user could scroll down.

I'm actually struggling on how I can make this whole part taking 100% percent of the screen under the header but to be allowed to have content under, do you have suggestions ? :)

**The page's Ionic React code**

```
<IonPage id='product-detail-page'>
  <Header searchbar={false} />

  <IonContent className='product-details-content'>
    <IonImg src={productDetailed.images[0]} alt='Image produit' />

    <div className='product-details-bottom-container'>
      <div className="product-details-infos ion-padding-horizontal">
        <div className="product-details-infos-left">
          <span className="product-details-title">{productDetailed.name}</span>
          <span className="product-details-dist">À 500m de toi</span>
        </div>

        <div className="product-details-infos-right">
          <img src="assets/img/shoplist/info-outline.svg" alt="Infos produit" />
        </div>

        <div className="product-details-price">
          {productDetailed.price}€
        </div>
      </div>
      <IonButton className="ion-margin-top ion-padding-horizontal">Acheter cet article</IonButton>
    </div>

  </IonContent>
</IonPage>
```

**An idea ?**
Actually my Header component is a Function Component, I was thinking to make it a Class one to put a ref on it and so get its height to then make div (with flexbox) for my image and my bottom part to have a dynamical height depending on the Header's one, is it a good idea ?

Thank you a lot !

Malo.

Comment: Why not force the `min-height` to be `100vh` in the styles of that component?

Comment: @DumbCoder7 thanks for answering, but I want to have content under this bottom. Also my header hasn't a fixed height, do you agree ?

Comment: @grallm have you considered giving the button a fixed position at the bottom? (doesn't fully solve the problem but worth a shot to start) You could feasibly add some more padding/margin-top above the picture too. And/Or a heading

Comment: @RachelGallen thanks for the answer, yeah I thought of it ;) If I don't succeed in a perfect solution I will maybe go for that, but I'm anyway interested to solve this problem because I can't find a solution! :O :)

Comment: @grallm yes the CSS in ionic can be frustrating. But it's one solution...

Comment: I'm thinking that I could also give a new 'ref' prop to Header which inside gives to the parent a container ref (maybe like this https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html#forwarding-refs-in-higher-order-components)